# Um float x==0 inclui valores como 0,7. Como mudar isso?

Tags: c, c++

Olá! Sou novo no mundo da programação e estou fazendo uma pequena calculadora. Fiz um if que encerra o programa se o usuário tentar dividir por 0, mas quando tento dividir por por exemplo 0,5 o programa entra nesse if e diz que não posso dividir nada por 0. Como consertar? Obrigado!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  float num1, num2;
  int op;

  printf("Hi there! Welcome to the best calculator ever! Choose the first number\n");
  scanf("%f", &num1);

  printf("Great! Now, choose what operation you want to execute: 1-Adition 2-Subtraction 3-Multiplication 4-Division\n");
  scanf("%d", &op);

  while (op > 4 || op < 1) {
    printf("This is not an option. Choose another one\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
  }

  printf("Almost there! Choose the second number!\n");
  scanf("%f", &num2);

   if (op == 1) {
     printf("Addition = %.3f \n", num1+num2);
     system("pause");
   }
   else if (op == 2) {
     printf("Subtraction = %.3f \n", num1-num2);
     system("pause");
   }
   else if(op == 3) {
     printf("Multiplication = %.3f \n", num1*num2);
     system("pause");
   }
   else if(op == 4 && num2 == 0) {
     printf("You can't divide anything by zero...I thought you knew better, son. \n");
     system("pause");
   }
   else if(op == 4) {
     printf("Division = %.3f \n", num1/num2);
     system("pause");
   }
}
```

Comment: `0,5` não é um número válido em `C`. Na maioria das linguagens de programação o separador decimal é o ponto, então você teria que dar de entrada `0.5`. Acredito que o `scanf` esteja capturando apenas a parte válida do `0,5`, que no caso seria o 0.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar o separador de partes decimais "." no lugar de ","

Comment: `0/4.2` não é erro!

Comment: Verdade, editei a resposta, obrigado